# Xamarin Android Emulator shows Black screen

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using Visual studio 2019
on an 8gb Pc Hp intel Pentium

I have this worry, now when i wanted to Debug my Xamarin Application, initially it worked fine, now the worry is I am getting a totally black screen when using the Android Emulator. Please anyone who has noticed something like this?

Comment: Does it work on real device? You can create a new blank project and deploy it on the emulator to check if the issue still exists .Or you can create a new emulator .

Comment: not even seeing my personal Mobile phone on Visual Studio

Comment: Create a new emulator and deploy it again .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT same

Comment: Make sure you select a x86 or x86_64 image.